# PHPでGithubとwebhookを利用して同期したい

Tags: php, github

PHPで、system()などが利用できないレンタルサーバーでGithubのwebhookを利用してGithubの特定リポジトリとサーバー上の特定ディレクトリの内容を同期したいのですが、
どの様なコードを書けばいいのでしょうか。

Comment: なにを同期したいのでしょうか。もうすこし具体的に質問を書いてください。

Comment: @h2so5 質問を編集させていただきましたが、このような内容で理解いただけたでしょうか。

Comment: リポジトリを履歴も含めて完全に同期したいのですか？ それとも最新のツリーが取得できれば良い？

Comment: @h2so5 最新のツリーを特定ディレクトリにコピーするというような形です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP`の`ZIPモジュール`が利用できる前提ですが、`github`からアーカイブをダウンロードして展開するだけです。

```
<?php

function rmdir_rec($dir)
{
    foreach (array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..')) as $file) {
        $path = $dir . '/' . $file;
        if (is_dir($path)) {
            rmdir_rec($path);
        } else {
            unlink($path);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}

function get_repo($zip_url, $dir)
{
    $temp_zip = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), '');
    file_put_contents($temp_zip, fopen($zip_url, 'r'));

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($temp_zip);

    if ($res === TRUE) {
        $ext_tmp = sys_get_temp_dir();
        var_dump($zip->extractTo($ext_tmp));
        if (file_exists($dir)) {
            rmdir_rec($dir);
        }
        rename($ext_tmp . '/' . $zip->getNameIndex(0), $dir);
        $zip->close();
    }

    unlink($temp_zip);
}

get_repo("https://github.com/mruby/mruby/archive/master.zip", "repo");
```